# How can I mirror a UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I have a `UIBezierPath` and I would like to get its mirror image. How can I accomplish this?

```
 // Method for generating a path
 UIBezierPath *myPath = [self generateAPathInBounds:boundingRect];

 // ? now I would like to mirror myPath ?
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
// Method for generating a path
UIBezierPath *myPath = [self generateAPathInBounds:boundingRect];

// Create two transforms, one to mirror across the x axis, and one to
// to translate the resulting path back into the desired boundingRect
CGAffineTransform mirrorOverXOrigin = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(boundingRect.width, 0);

// Apply these transforms to the path
[myPath applyTransform:mirrorOverXOrigin];
[myPath applyTransform:translate];
```

Comment: Instead of `boundingRect.width`, I would use `boundingRect.midX * 2`.

Answer (score 4):

It should be noted that you might need additional code depending on where in the overall view the path you are trying to mirror is.

If you are trying to mirror a path that takes up the whole view (or is at least flush with the 0 coordinate of the axis you are mirroring over), then @wbarksdale's answer will work for you.  However, if you are trying to mirror a path thats a small section of the overall view thats somewhere in the middle of the view, then you need to do more work.  In general, the algorithm is like this

```
  //this rect should be the bounds of your path within its superviews
  //coordinate system
  let rect = myPath.bounds
  //first, you need to move the view all the way to the left
  //because otherwise, if you mirror it in its current position, 
  //the view will be thrown way off screen to the left
  path.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -rect.origin.x, y: 0))
  //then you mirror it
  path.apply(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1))
  //then, after its mirrored, move it back to its original position
  path.apply(CGAffineTransform(translationX: rect.origin.x + rect.width, y: 0))
```

In general, the algorithm should be

1. Move the path either to the very left or the very top of the view 
   depending on whether you are flipping horizontally or vertically, using `CGAffineTransform(translateX....)`
2. Mirror the view using `CGAffineTransform(scaleX....`
3. Move the view back to its original position using `CGAffineTransform(translateX....)`

Comment: this is great!!

Answer (score -3):

I case your `path` in not centered to `(0,0)` this code is correct:

```
// Method for generating a path
UIBezierPath *myPath = [self generateAPathInBounds:boundingRect];

// Create two transforms, one to mirror across the x axis, and one to
// to translate the resulting path back into the desired boundingRect
CGAffineTransform mirrorOverXOrigin = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(CGRectGetMidX(boundingRect), 0);
CGAffineTransform translateBack = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-CGRectGetMidX(boundingRect), 0);

// Apply these transforms to the path
[myPath applyTransform:translate];
[myPath applyTransform:mirrorOverXOrigin];
[myPath applyTransform:translateBack];
```

Comment: What is "true" about this - it appears to be copy-pasted from another answer with an addition that has no explanation?

Comment: @Mike my answer contains 3 necessary transformations

Comment: Why is the third necessary? You copied the code in the accepted answer and added code without modifying the comment, so there is no explanation.