# Text path created by CTFontCreatePathForGlyph is flipped

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I am trying to achieve text drawn inside `CAShapeLayer`. For this purpose I need to create `UIBezierPath` from the text. Based on [text path solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231963/how-to-get-emoji-path-in-ios?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) should all works fine, but sadly I can't find what is wrong.

The path created by `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(runFont, glyph, nil)` has drawn letter from the flipped side.

[image]

The code converted to **Swift 4**

```
      func initializeTextLayer() {
        let fontName: CFString = "Noteworthy-Light" as CFString

        let letters     = CGMutablePath()
        let font        = CTFontCreateWithName(fontName, 50, nil)
        let attrString  = NSAttributedString(string: "TEST", attributes: [kCTFontAttributeName as NSAttributedStringKey : font])
        let line        = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attrString)
        let runArray    = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line)

        for runIndex in 0..<CFArrayGetCount(runArray) {

            let run     : CTRun =  unsafeBitCast(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(runArray, runIndex), to: CTRun.self)
            let dictRef : CFDictionary = CTRunGetAttributes(run)
            let dict    : NSDictionary = dictRef as NSDictionary
            let runFont = dict[kCTFontAttributeName as String] as! CTFont

            for runGlyphIndex in 0..<CTRunGetGlyphCount(run) {
                let thisGlyphRange  = CFRangeMake(runGlyphIndex, 1)
                var glyph           = CGGlyph()
                var position        = CGPoint.zero
                CTRunGetGlyphs(run, thisGlyphRange, &glyph)
                CTRunGetPositions(run, thisGlyphRange, &position)

                let letter          = CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(runFont, glyph, nil)
                let t               = CGAffineTransform(translationX: position.x, y: position.y)
                if let letter = letter  {
                    letters.addPath(letter, transform: t)
                }
            }
        }
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
        path.append(UIBezierPath(cgPath: letters))

        let pathLayer               = CAShapeLayer()
        pathLayer.path              = path.cgPath
        self.layer.addSublayer(pathLayer)
    }
```

Any ideas what can I do to mirror it ? I found something [mirror path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958408/how-can-i-mirror-a-uibezierpath?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but it didn't get any results.

Comment: Almost certainly due to iOS's y-axis being inverse of Mac-OS's. Try saving graphics context & scaling context by (+1, -1) before rendering, then restoring context.

Comment: You can't get current graphics context outside `draw(in rect: CGRect)`. I am using only `CAShapeLayer`'s for this. Am I wrong ? Please give me some light on it.

Comment: Apologies - it's a CALayer. The solution still holds, but you need to use `CGTransform` whilst creating the path (which you're doing anyway for the translation) to also invert the y-axis.

Comment: I see your point, working on solution !

Comment: Well done - you beat me to it! You should actually post your answer as an actual answer, not as an edit to the question. That way you can A) mark your answer as "correct", B) get upvotes on the answer too...

Comment: @Grimxn Sure, I did it. In 2 days I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Grimxn said: I have to do scale and translation.

In super view of custom layer inside `draw(in rect: CGRect)` added following lines of code.

```
 func updateTextLayerPath() {
    if let pth = popupLayer.textLayerPath {

        UIColor.red.setStroke()

        // glyph path is inverted, so flip vertically
        let flipY = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1.0)

        // glyph path may be offset on the x coord, and by the height (because it's flipped)
        let translate = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -pth.bounds.origin.x, y: pth.bounds.size.height + pth.bounds.origin.y)

        // apply the transforms
        pth.apply(flipY)
        pth.apply(translate)

        // stroke the path
        pth.stroke()
    }
}
```

`textLayerPath` is a stored property in custom `CAShapeLayer` which gets updates inside `layoutSubviews` of the super view.

Hope it will be helpful for everyone else who is going to face this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also provide a transform to the `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph` method to flip the returned path.

```
// Mirror the glyph about the x-axis so it not upside down
var flipVertically = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
let cgPath = CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(font, glyph, &flipVertically)
```